# How to use Java Dynamic Array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I am currently taking a Java Programming class and we are on the topic of dynamic arrays.  We were asked to write a program using dynamic arrays that would print out the Fibonacci Sequence.

This is what I have:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private static int[] data;

    public static void DynamicArray() {
        data = new int[1];
    }

    public static int get(int position) {
        if (position >= data.length){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return data[position];
        }
    }

    public static void put(int position, int value) {
        if(position >= data.length) {
            int newSize = 2 * position;
            int[] newData = new int[newSize];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
            data = newData;
        }
        data[position] = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\nFibonacci Sequence:\n");
        System.out.println(data[0]);
        for(int i = 2; i< = 20; i++) {
            data[i] = data[i-1] + data[i-2];
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is your definition of dynamic array?

Comment: What do  I need to add to this code to make it work?

Comment: @Dan **Dynamic Array== Arraylist** java impl or a `growing array contrary to fixed size array`

Comment: Dan, my teacher defined it as an array that can have its length increased as more items are added to it.  I don't know if this is a best practice, but this is what she wants as assignment.

Comment: @PremGenError, see? I wanted to see if that was the definition in his problem :)

Comment: @conflittimat, what is not working exactly?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to print out any values from the data array.  My teacher was very vague on how to add more values to the array using this method.  Do I have the wrong access modifiers on my methods?

Answer (score 1):

Array is static because you create it with size. For dynamic, use ArrayList. ArrayList is a Array too. ArrayList has default size of 10 and growth 25%(total size) when reaching 75% total size. But it's slow because of when ArrayList reach 75%size, java will create a new Array and copy data to new one in memory. You can use LinkedList, faster for read-write data than ArrayList-faster for read data.

Answer (score 0):

Does it counts as dynamic array if you use the .push() method? If it's OK you can just count the next number in Fibonacci Sequence and use MyArray.push(currentFibonacci);

Comment: She wants us to use dynamic arrays and system.out.println(); with the help of a for loop to print the numbers.  We haven't learned .push(); yet.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Arrays are static. Once they are initialised, they can not 'grow'.
There are several data structures for solving this problem (linked lists for example).

If you want to resize an array, you'll have to create a new one with the wanted size and then copy all entrys from the old array to the new one.
Java's implementation of this kind of "dynamic array" is the ArrayList. Yet this is not very fast

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing don't worry its a lot simpler then you are making it look at the code I have that does what you want

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

        public class DynamicArray
        {
            public static void

d main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("How Long Do You Want To see the Fibonacci Series?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Length = scan.nextInt();

            int[] Fibonacci = new int[Length];
            Fibonacci[0] = 0;
            Fibonacci[1] = 1;
            System.out.println("Fibonacci Series");

            System.out.println(Fibonacci[0]);

            for (int i = 2; i<Length; i++){
                Fibonacci[i]=Fibonacci[i-2]+Fibonacci[i-1];

        System.out.println(Fibonacci[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

So what is happening here is that the length variable I declared is inputted by the user determining how far the array will print the Fibonacci series it is rather simple once you know what you are trying to do. So this is what you need since this is what your teacher wants hope it helps. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (sequence<4000000)
            {
                   i++;
                   sequence = fibonacciSequence[0]+fibonacciSequence[1];
                   System.out.println(sequence);
                   if (i%2!=0)
                   {
                     fibonacciSequence[0]=sequence;  
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     fibonacciSequence[1]=sequence;  
                   }
                   if (sequence%2==0)
                   {
                    sumEvenTerm = sumEvenTerm + sequence; 
                   }
             }
```

@Randy thanks for your answer here. In this case, we do know the length of the fibonnaci sequence. In some cases, we do not know the length. What we know is the value of the some fibonnaci number. We can't use the above program.

You can change the value in the while loop to suit your needs.